# SQL Server 2012 Computed column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, calculated-columns

```
ID  Date    Value   Average
1   10/5/2017   15  15
2   10/6/2017   25  20
3   10/7/2017   35  25
4   10/8/2017   45  35
5   10/9/2017   55  45
6   10/10/2017  65  55
7   10/11/2017  75  65
```

If this is my table, I want average to be a computed column and its formula in general is average of previous 3 row's Value column.

```
(Ex. for 2nd row it is (25+15)/2 )
```

How can i do such a thing in computed column? Is there any better way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say last three, that implies an order, which requires a query with an order by clause.  Computed columns are not meant to work that way, they are based on a single row.  I agree with TheGameisway in that you should use a view. Lead and Lag functions might be useful.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me with an example of that? I never used lead and lag functions

Answer (score 2):

i would go with a view and use `avg` windows function

```
 select 
    id,
    date,
    value,
    avg(value) over (order by id)
    from table
```

**Updated answer:** you could use frames clause like below

<kbd>[Working Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/737150)</kbd>

```
;with cte(id,date,val)
as
(

select 1   ,'10/5/2017'  ,  15  UNION ALL
select 2   ,'10/6/2017'  ,  25  UNION ALL
select 3   ,'10/7/2017'  ,  35  UNION ALL
select 4   ,'10/8/2017'  ,  45  UNION ALL
select 5   ,'10/9/2017'  ,  55  UNION ALL
select 6   ,'10/10/2017',  65  UNION ALL
select 7   ,'10/11/2017',  75  
)
SELECT *,avg(VAL) OVER (ORDER BY id rows between 2 PRECEDING  and current row ) FROM CTE
```

Comment: For each row the value should be the average of 3 previous row values. I am unable to get that using your solution.

Comment: Your second row example doesn't say that `(25+15)/2 `

Comment: if it has previous 3 rows then its average of 3 rows otherwise previous 2 rows or previous 1 row. In my question i included the present row and previous 2 rows

Comment: Thanks,search for  Itzik Ben-Gan Windows functions for more details

Comment: I need to get this lead and lag functions capability on sql server 2008. I see that these analytic functions were released in 2012 version. 

Can someone please suggest me a solution without using lead-lag functions ?